# c++ grpc call with SslCredentials makes coredump always

Tags: c++, ssl, grpc, ros, coredump

thanks in advance.

I'm trying to make client program for grpc comm in ros(melodic)system.
but when i call any rpc method with sslcredentials, it always makes coredump.

my env is below

- ubuntu / c++
- ros melodic
- with InsecureChannelCredentials, it works fine
- with sslCredention, it makes always coredump
- testing with modified sample codes(it's running on normal ubuntu system not ros), works fine.

Actually, I expect ssl handshake fail as a result of program. but i do not know why it makes crash. I guess it is related with program launch environment(this program is for ros) but i'm not sure.

if you guys know why, please let me know.

here is my code

```
 HelloRequest request;
  request.set_name("test");
  DirUtils::readWholeFile("roots.pem", cacert);
  HelloReply reply;
  ClientContext context;

  grpc::SslCredentialsOptions ssl_opts = {cacert.c_str(), "", ""};
  ssl_opts.pem_root_certs = cacert.c_str();
  auto channel_creds = grpc::SslCredentials(ssl_opts);

#if 1
  auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:50051", channel_creds);
#else
  auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());
#endif

  std::unique_ptr<Greeter::Stub> stub(Greeter::NewStub(channel));
  CLOGE("runrunrun");
  grpc::Status status = stub->SayHello(&context, request, &reply);
  if (status.ok()) {
    CLOGE("%s", reply.message().c_str());
  } else {
    std::cout << status.error_code() << ": " << status.error_message() << std::endl;
    CLOGE("RPC failed");
  }
```

Below is grpc trace with
GRPC_TRACE=round_robin,connectivity_state,pick_first dns_resolver subchannel subchannel_pool

with SslCredention

```
[ INFO] [1647838520.766193359]: [GRPC][CloudRoboTaxiProxy] : 
D0321 13:55:20.766466283   10705 ev_posix.cc:172]            Using polling engine: epollex
D0321 13:55:20.766535088   10705 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "grpclb"
D0321 13:55:20.766546645   10705 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "priority_experimental"
D0321 13:55:20.766551896   10705 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "weighted_target_experimental"
D0321 13:55:20.766556531   10705 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "pick_first"
D0321 13:55:20.766560778   10705 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "round_robin"
D0321 13:55:20.766565164   10705 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "ring_hash_experimental"
D0321 13:55:20.766572233   10705 dns_resolver_ares.cc:495]   Using ares dns resolver
D0321 13:55:20.766600439   10705 certificate_provider_registry.cc:33] registering certificate provider factory for "file_watcher"
D0321 13:55:20.766608461   10705 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "cds_experimental"
D0321 13:55:20.766615145   10705 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "xds_cluster_impl_experimental"
D0321 13:55:20.766620460   10705 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "xds_cluster_resolver_experimental"
D0321 13:55:20.766625384   10705 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "xds_cluster_manager_experimental"
[ERROR] [1647838520.766839781]: [GRPC][CloudRoboTaxiProxy] : RUNRUNRUN
I0321 13:55:20.766971552   10705 connectivity_state.cc:182]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x56429ac907d8]: get current state: IDLE
I0321 13:55:20.766995225   10705 connectivity_state.cc:182]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x56429ac907d8]: get current state: IDLE
I0321 13:55:20.767014411   10705 connectivity_state.cc:159]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x56429ac907d8]: IDLE -> CONNECTING (started resolving, OK)
I0321 13:55:20.830628662   10705 pick_first.cc:144]          Pick First 0x56429aca6a70 created.
I0321 13:55:20.830652683   10705 pick_first.cc:261]          Pick First 0x56429aca6a70 received update with 1 addresses
I0321 13:55:20.830661559   10705 subchannel_list.h:363]      [pick_first 0x56429aca6a70] Creating subchannel list 0x56429aca6de0 for 1 subchannels
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

with InsecureCredentials

```
[ INFO] [1647838665.719818173]: [GRPC][CloudRoboTaxiProxy] : 
D0321 13:57:45.720068078   18636 ev_posix.cc:172]            Using polling engine: epollex
D0321 13:57:45.720134657   18636 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "grpclb"
D0321 13:57:45.720145342   18636 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "priority_experimental"
D0321 13:57:45.720150278   18636 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "weighted_target_experimental"
D0321 13:57:45.720154793   18636 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "pick_first"
D0321 13:57:45.720158925   18636 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "round_robin"
D0321 13:57:45.720163193   18636 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "ring_hash_experimental"
D0321 13:57:45.720170070   18636 dns_resolver_ares.cc:495]   Using ares dns resolver
D0321 13:57:45.720196517   18636 certificate_provider_registry.cc:33] registering certificate provider factory for "file_watcher"
D0321 13:57:45.720203835   18636 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "cds_experimental"
D0321 13:57:45.720209495   18636 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "xds_cluster_impl_experimental"
D0321 13:57:45.720214363   18636 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "xds_cluster_resolver_experimental"
D0321 13:57:45.720219090   18636 lb_policy_registry.cc:42]   registering LB policy factory for "xds_cluster_manager_experimental"
[ERROR] [1647838665.720435529]: [GRPC][CloudRoboTaxiProxy] : runrunrun
I0321 13:57:45.720566714   18636 connectivity_state.cc:182]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x564b8c974788]: get current state: IDLE
I0321 13:57:45.720589783   18636 connectivity_state.cc:182]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x564b8c974788]: get current state: IDLE
I0321 13:57:45.720607804   18636 connectivity_state.cc:159]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x564b8c974788]: IDLE -> CONNECTING (started resolving, OK)
I0321 13:57:51.813909546   18636 pick_first.cc:144]          Pick First 0x564b8c98ab70 created.
I0321 13:57:51.813938340   18636 pick_first.cc:261]          Pick First 0x564b8c98ab70 received update with 1 addresses
I0321 13:57:51.813947230   18636 subchannel_list.h:363]      [pick_first 0x564b8c98ab70] Creating subchannel list 0x564b8c98ae20 for 1 subchannels
I0321 13:57:51.813989918   18636 subchannel_list.h:383]      [pick_first 0x564b8c98ab70] subchannel list 0x564b8c98ae20 index 0: Created subchannel 0x564b8c6321a0 for address 127.0.0.1:50051 args={}
I0321 13:57:51.814000974   18636 subchannel_list.h:310]      [pick_first 0x564b8c98ab70] subchannel list 0x564b8c98ae20 index 0 of 1 (subchannel 0x564b8c6321a0): starting watch (from IDLE)
I0321 13:57:51.814004907   18636 ref_counted.h:86]           SubchannelList:0x564b8c98ae28 /home/omega/tools/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/subchannel_list.h:319 ref 1 -> 2 Watcher
I0321 13:57:51.814114063   18636 connectivity_state.cc:182]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x564b8c974788]: get current state: CONNECTING
I0321 13:57:51.814149960   18636 subchannel_list.h:243]      [pick_first 0x564b8c98ab70] subchannel list 0x564b8c98ae20 index 0 of 1 (subchannel 0x564b8c6321a0): connectivity changed: state=CONNECTING, shutting_down=0, pending_watcher=0x564b8c98b0c0
I0321 13:57:51.814507743   18636 subchannel_list.h:243]      [pick_first 0x564b8c98ab70] subchannel list 0x564b8c98ae20 index 0 of 1 (subchannel 0x564b8c6321a0): connectivity changed: state=READY, shutting_down=0, pending_watcher=0x564b8c98b0c0
I0321 13:57:51.814516269   18636 pick_first.cc:457]          Pick First 0x564b8c98ab70 selected subchannel 0x564b8c6321a0
I0321 13:57:51.814521702   18636 connectivity_state.cc:159]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x564b8c974788]: CONNECTING -> READY (helper, OK)
I0321 13:57:51.814551635   18636 connectivity_state.cc:122]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_transport[0x7fa2900025d8]: add watcher 0x564b8c97c450
[ERROR] [1647838671.815124034]: [GRPC][CloudRoboTaxiProxy] : Hello test
I0321 13:57:51.815213570   18636 pick_first.cc:158]          Pick First 0x564b8c98ab70 Shutting down
I0321 13:57:51.815222628   18636 subchannel_list.h:404]      [pick_first 0x564b8c98ab70] Shutting down subchannel_list 0x564b8c98ae20
I0321 13:57:51.815259904   18636 subchannel_list.h:330]      [pick_first 0x564b8c98ab70] subchannel list 0x564b8c98ae20 index 0 of 1 (subchannel 0x564b8c6321a0): canceling connectivity watch (shutdown)
I0321 13:57:51.815267166   18636 ref_counted.h:182]          SubchannelList:0x564b8c98ae28 /home/omega/tools/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/subchannel_list.h:146 unref 2 -> 1 Watcher dtor
I0321 13:57:51.815275667   18636 subchannel_list.h:287]      [pick_first 0x564b8c98ab70] subchannel list 0x564b8c98ae20 index 0 of 1 (subchannel 0x564b8c6321a0): unreffing subchannel (shutdown)
I0321 13:57:51.815298707   18636 ref_counted.h:182]          SubchannelList:0x564b8c98ae28 /home/omega/tools/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/subchannel_list.h:200 unref 1 -> 0 shutdown
I0321 13:57:51.815323065   18636 subchannel_list.h:396]      [pick_first 0x564b8c98ab70] Destroying subchannel_list 0x564b8c98ae20
I0321 13:57:51.815328477   18636 pick_first.cc:150]          Destroying Pick First 0x564b8c98ab70
I0321 13:57:51.815342666   18636 connectivity_state.cc:159]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x564b8c974788]: READY -> SHUTDOWN (shutdown from API, OK)
I0321 13:57:51.815388688   18636 connectivity_state.cc:159]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_transport[0x7fa2900025d8]: READY -> SHUTDOWN (close_transport, OK)
I0321 13:57:51.815397929   18636 connectivity_state.cc:167]  ConnectivityStateTracker client_transport[0x7fa2900025d8]: notifying watcher 0x564b8c97c450: READY -> SHUTDOWN
I0321 13:57:51.815417452   18636 connectivity_state.cc:79]   watcher 0x564b8c97c450: delivering async notification for SHUTDOWN (OK)
D0321 13:57:51.815500746   18636 init.cc:179]                grpc_shutdown starts clean-up now
[ INFO] [1647838671.815908345]: [GRPC][~CloudRoboTaxiProxy] :
```

if you needs more information, please tell me

Comment: Hello jaegwan, can you provide a complete [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be reproduced?

Comment: @J.P.S Thanks for comment. i solved this issue. 
my ros node program which i tested, is using openssl for websocketpp.
i think it make some conflict with grpc's ssl(boringssl?).
After delete websocketpp parts, it works fine

Comment: Great! Maybe, that's an insight, you want to share with the community via a complete answer?